# Example of modified configuration for gatsby-plugin-offline?

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to get my head around gatsby-plugin-offline.  The README that comes with the plugin gives an example of the default options, but the example isn't in a format that can be pasted into gatsby-config.js for playing-around purposes.

I'm struggling to figure out how to do that; e.g. if you just cut and paste, modify for the different syntax, it bombs out on the ${rootDir} reference.

I'm pretty familiar with service workers, but Gatsby has a lot of foo under the hood, and I'm not conversant enough yet with the system to know where to start looking for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `rootDir` must give the path to your *build* directory, e.g.:

```
const rootDir = `${__dirname}/public`
```